# A Sitecore user sees significantly more items having been updated on publish than another user with same permissions

Tags: publishing, editor-user-permissions

**Scenario:**

- Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 151207 Hotfix 114141-2)
- two Sitecore users (non-admin)
- both accounts with almost same permission roles
- publishing from the same root item path:

  - smart publish `true`
  - subitems `true`
  - related items `false`
  - languages: all available

**Issue oberservation**

1) When user "A" publishes a certain item including subitems the result is:

```
Items created: 0
Items deleted: 0
Items updated: 39
Items skipped: 48
```

2) When user "B" publishes the same item including subitems, the result is:

```
Items created: 0
Items deleted: 0
Items updated: 32
Items skipped: 29
```

For each user the number of items affected due to the publish are identical to the web-delivery 1 and web-delivery 2 (Web-databases).

**Expected behaviour**

For both users, when publishing from the same root item with same publishing settings, the number of updated & skipped items should be identical.

**Does anybody know what could be the cause of this**, or how to investigate where there might be a difference causing such an effect?

Comment: This is usually permissions-related, and you mention they have "almost same" permissions. Are you able to provide more details around the permissions that have been granted? Typically what has happened here is a related item (like a media file or datasource) which one user can edit but the other cannot.

Comment: You basically confirmed what I thought might be the root cause of different item updates on publish, due to permissions. However, I checked each involved item and related item in the affected tree and…
1) both users with their corresponding roles have the same view, edit & etc. permissions on all sub- and related items (also from media library)
2) actually most of the items have been created by user B, who sees less affected updated items on publish
I didn't go further into the roles & permissions because user A has only specific additional roles not related to content items or languages.

Comment: Another related permission issue is workflow state permissions, have you checked workflow permissions are the same between users?

Comment: There is indeed a Workflow on the root item, which is in the final workflow step. However, both users have "Workflow state - write" permissions; and for the other permissions on that workflow / workflow states, suprisingly user B has more access than user A – so I'd expect on publishing to have user B more updated items.

Can you elaborate your thoughts or experience, how related items on items affect the "items updated" stats on publishing, even if "Related items publish" is DISabled?

Comment: It has been a while since I looked through the logic for publishing, but back a few years ago the related items calculations had some issues and even when 'false' it still counted certain elements multiple times (or skipped some). I could not figure out the exact metric, but it led to strange items updated counts being displayed.